# I'm trying to get this program to ask for the book title and number but something is not right with the while loop

Tags: c, loops, input, while-loop, scanf

The program supposed to ask for the book title and number repeatedly until the user inputs `"end"` for the book title after which it should stop.

But when I run the program after the first loop of inputs, the second loop onwards acts very weird and I am not getting a chance to type a book name or end the program. I tried using `fgets` but that didn't work either. It did work a little better but in the second loop it would print the two print statements and then ask for an input.

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, temp, bk_no[20], lib_size = 0;
    char bk_name[20], end[3]="end";
    printf("\n===========ACCESSING LIBRARY===========\n\n   (Type end to close the library)\n");

    while ( lib_size < sizeof bk_no/sizeof bk_no[0] )       //while lib_size<20->(20*4)/4
    {
        printf("\nWhat is the name of the book?\n");
        scanf_s("%s", &bk_name);

        if ( strcmp(bk_name, end)==0 )
            break;

        printf("What is the books number in the series?\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &bk_no[lib_size]);

        if ( bk_no[lib_size]==-1 )
            break;

        lib_size++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `scanf_s()` call has two problems, 1. It's missing a length parameter AFAIK. 2. You should not pass the address of the array, the array is already a pointer to it's first element.

Comment: @sheldon In such examples it would help to also include what input you are passing and the output produced when you run the program. It may not bear any responsibility for the problem... but helps eliminate some possible cases where such things can happen if the input breaks the allowed buffer bounds. etc.etc.

Answer (score 3):

1. `end[3]` should be `end[4]` ... to account for the `'\0'` at the end of the string.
2. `scanf_s()` should be passed size parameter for the `"%s"`, you are using it as if you are using `scanf()` and not `scanf_s()` [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx).
3. You are passing the address of the array to `scanf_s()` that is wrong with both, `scanf_s()` and `scanf()`.

   Arrays, are automatically pointers to their first elements in this context so you don't need the `&` address of operator to pass one to `scanf()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @iharob... you are better at this editing thing than me :-)